# Any way to set interval between requests using AFNetworking?

Tags: ios, api, afnetworking

I'm using AFNetworking as network library. The API provider limits API calls to 1 call per second. Is there any convenient way to set minimum interval limit between requests with AFHTTPRequestOperationManager? If not, what's the proper or best way to implement such interval limitation?

Comment: whats your main goal? how much minimum interval you want between requests

Comment: @DekelMaman I want a 1 second interval between every two requests.